# Translated URLs in Django that work simultaneously for all languages

Tags: django, internationalization, django-urls

Given a view defined by a function `about_us`, I would like it to be accessible by either one of these URLs:

- `/about/`
- `/acerca-de/`

In a way that requesting any of those activates the corresponding language and renders the view, but both URLs remain accessible at all times regardless of the currently active language.

I would also like to reverse these URLs inside templates using the path name, so `reverse('about_us')` can give me the URL that corresponds to the currently active language.

Django offers a [mechanism for translating URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#translating-url-patterns) by wrapping the string matchers for path objects in `gettext_lazy` so reverse URL resolution can return the one appropriate for the current language, but AFAIK only one of the URLs works at any given time, depending on the current language.

If I instead define two path objects then I can point them to the same view wrapped by some view decorator that activates the given language first, but then I lose the ability to perform reverse URL resolution and I am forced to perform some ugly tricks to get links to respect the current language.

Has anyone found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### It could create a common path to dispatch the translated urls to target views. for sake of dispatching url, make use of a register decorater for it.

utils.py

```
from django.utils.text import slugify
import functools

translated_urls = {}

def register_translated_url(trans_url=''):
    def decorator(viewfunc):
        nonlocal trans_url
        if trans_url and isinstance(trans_url, str):
            trans_url = slugify(trans_url)
            translated_urls[trans_url] = viewfunc
        @functools.wraps(viewfunc)
        def wraped(request, *args, **kwargs):
            return viewfunc(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return wraped
    return decorator
```

urls.py

```
# the below urlpatterns must append to the end to capture all slug url
urlpatterns += [
    path('<slug:slug>/', translated_url, name='translated_url'),
]
```

views.py

```
from . import utils
from django.http import Http404
# other codes
@utils.register_translated_url(trans_url='blabla')
def postvideo(request):
    pass

def translated_url(request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    print(utils.translated_urls)
    viewfunc = utils.translated_urls.get(slug)
    if viewfunc:
        return viewfunc(request, *args, **kwargs)
    raise Http404
```

Comment: I am looking for something that can can integrate better with the rest of the Django functionality for reversing and resolving URLs.

Comment: You could dig something out from format_suffix_patterns function of django-rest-framework.